# Rewrite or possibly .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I tried to deploy my PHP application into my client's server. At my dev machine it works and in my own website it also works fine. But it didn't work in my client's server.

It seemed that Apache doesn't run .htaccess therefor rewrite doesn't work resulting a 404 page.

The server's using a fresh installed of CentOS 5.

Here's httpd.conf that I think is responsible to run .htaccess

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

From phpinfo, rewrite and alias modules are loading.

And here's a piece of my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule news_(.*)_page_(.*)\.htm$ /sub_domain/?mod=page&cat=$1&pid=$2
```

I tried to create error in .htaccess but no error happened.

Would someone know how the solution to this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you can check the apache config httpd.conf see if it has "AllowOverride directive" set to 'allow'

Comment: It doesn't work also. Thank you anyway.
Now, I'm starting pulling my already gone hairs..